# Mark checkbox based on value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a vba-written Macro that populates a form I have in worksheet "Design" based on values in a row in worksheet "info". Once all fields are populated in the form, it is then printed to PDF, then does the same for every row with data. On the form I have check boxes that are manually marked after the PDF creation; HOWEVER, i was wondering if we can include VBA in the same Macro that would mark the a checkbox based on the specific value in a cell within the row of the "info" worksheet. to make this easier, the cell has a data validation that would only allow the selection of specific values.

For example, if c3 = rain, then mark box in d4, if c3 = sunshine, then mark box in d5, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assuming ActiveX checkbox control is used on worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call UpdateChkBox
End Sub

Sub UpdateChkBox()
    Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = (Range("c3") = "rain")
    Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox2.Value = (Range("c3") = "sunshine")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Will I be able to include this in my general VBA  (populates form and prints per every row) or does this have to be assigned separately to the box?

Comment: It's a worksheet event `Worksheet_Change`. Right click on sheet table > View Code > paste the code.  You don't need to assign any sub code to the box （checkbox control).  _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Worksheet object events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/worksheet-object-events?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: I keep getting and error. I think its because the form and the check boxes are in a different sheet of the same workbook since it works when I test it with everything in the same sheet. Do you know if this vba code works across worksheets or is additional code needed ?

Comment: Yes. The sheetname ( `Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1....` ) should be changed.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but that is what I have tried before my last comment and i continue to get "object does not support this property or method" my code is Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call UpdateChkBox
End Sub

Sub UpdateChkBox()
   Sheets("claims").CheckBox1.Value = (Range("x2") = "1 self-limited or minor problem")
End Sub

Comment: Does my code work before adding new sheet?

Comment: Yes code works fine when check box and value cell are in same sheet. referencing a value cell in a different sheet is where the error occurs. Other codes Ive found are the same as yours. not sure why its not working for me.

Comment: Which line raises the error "object does not support this property or method"? Please qualify the range with sheet object `Sheets(...).Range("x2")...`.

Comment: the second line gets highlighted in debug: Sheets("claims").CheckBox1.Value = (Range("x2") = "1 self-limited or minor problem") . Not sure what you mean by "qualify the range with sheet object"

Comment: Change `Range("x2")` to `Sheets(...).Range("x2")...`.

Comment: thank you! my final code: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call UpdateChkBox
   
End Sub

Sub UpdateChkBox()
Sheets("design").CheckBox1.Value = Sheets("claims").Range("X2") = "1 self-limited or minor problem"

End Sub

I put the checkbox worksheet first then the other with its value cell range.